# Python in Replit: Printing the biggest value

Tags: python-3.8

I'm very inexperienced with python and I'm not sure how to gather integer inputs from a user and then print the biggest variable and I'm so confused!

here's my code

```py
def printBiggest(myA, myB, myC):

  if (myC >= myB and myC >= myA):     
    print (myC)
  elif (myB >= myC and myB >= myA):   
    print (myB)
  else:                               
    print (myA)



 return None  
input(" Please enter three numbers: ")
x,y,z = input(int(), input(int(), input(int()                                
x = myA
y = myB
z = myC
print ("The biggest number is:", printBiggest)
```

my prompts:

TODO: STEP 1: prompt the user for 3 integer values and store them in 3 separate variables x, y, and z

NOTE: don't forget convert each input string to an integer using the int() funciton, before you store it in your variable

TODO: Step 2: call your printBiggest() function here, passing it the 3 values you collected (x, y, and z)

NOTE: your function will do the printing, so there is nothing else to do below this line